# Grabbing and pulling image causes image to go out of bounds

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, function

I am using react-zoom-pan-pinch library for zoomIn and zoomOut. The problem I’m having is when grabbing and pulling the image, it goes out of bounds. I read docs, and it seems I need to use limitToBounds={true} which helps, but then it won’t help 100% because the image still goes out of bounds. It should be stuck to bounds , so my question is how to make the image stuck to bounds/borders, you should not be able to pull it out of bounds(all functionalities should work, just image stuck to bounds/borders).

try it here: https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-bash-bzvrwf?file=/src/App.tsx

Image of my problem:

[image]

```js
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

import { TransformWrapper, TransformComponent } from "react-zoom-pan-pinch";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="element">
        <TransformWrapper limitToBounds={true}>
          {({ zoomIn, zoomOut, resetTransform }: any) => (
            <React.Fragment>
              <div style={{ border: "1px solid black" }}>
                <div className="tools">
                  <button onClick={zoomIn}>+</button>
                  <button onClick={zoomOut}>-</button>
                  <button onClick={resetTransform}>x</button>
                </div>
                <TransformComponent>
                  <img
                    width="100%"
                    src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/02/24/15/41/dog-647528__340.jpg"
                    alt="test 2"
                  />
                </TransformComponent>
              </div>
            </React.Fragment>
          )}
        </TransformWrapper>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add these props inside the TransformWrapper component:

```
  alignmentAnimation={{ sizeX: 0, sizeY: 0 }}
```

your example:

[codesandboxexample](https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-dawn-zvvncd?file=/src/App.tsx:350-409)

hope that help :)

Comment: you can read about it in there docs: https://prc5.github.io/react-zoom-pan-pinch/?path=/story/docs-props--page , under section  alignmentAnimation

Comment: it seems to have other problems now, when using your codesandbox, try to zoom in and zoom out many times from different angles, then you can see that it gets still out of bounds/borders

Comment: add the props centerZoomedOut={true}.  I edit the codesandboxexample if you want to look :)